# Cropping keypoints vs. cropping image and finding keypoints

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Given an image of many items, with all of its bounding box known in pixel coordinates.

I am trying to extract a region (surrounding) around each of the items, calculate its descriptors and features using AKAZE, to do comparison with one another.

However I realised that this might be too slow, since it involves:

1) cropping each and every single item to generate many images then,

2) detecting and computing on each image to generate the keypoints and descriptors.

Alternatively, to speed things up, I was thinking of:

1) Resizing the entire image, then perform the detecting and computing of keypoints once.

2) Then to obtain the keypoint of a particular object, we simply retrieve the set of precalculated keypoints corresponding to the objects location.

My question is this method functionally sound, and that if there are any consequences to this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this second strategy is a fine way to go. To do this efficiently you should supply a mask argument in the call to OpenCV's `detectAndCompute` (or `detect` if you're using that). Your mask should be the same size as your image. In each pixel of the mask you would have zero for that pixel if it does not lie within at least one detection region, otherwise its value is positive (255 for a uchar mask).

In fact with the first strategy you can have a problem at the borders of your  detection regions, where feature points can be missed. This is because feature detection and descriptor computation require processing a small window of pixels around each pixel (which are not available at the borders). To correctly handle this you would need to enlarge the detection regions before cropping.

Concerning efficiency you should be aware that there is an overhead with the second approach, which is that the full image will undergo some image pre-processing before feature detection. For AKAZE this is nonlinear diffusion and for others such as SIFT and SURF this is image convolution. These are needed to built so-called image pyramids. In situations where you only have a few detections the first strategy can be more efficient (the overhead of image cropping is tiny relative to the image pre processing).